# Getting an Error while making New React App

Tags: reactjs

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/electron-to-chromium: 00270000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\\ws\\deps\\openssl\\openssl\\providers\\implementations\\ciphers\\ciphercommon_gcm.c:320:
npm ERR!
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\\Users\\SteepRise\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\\_logs\\2023-12-19T06_58_29_179Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried various methods that are available, but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me tackle this issue? Please assist me in resolving it. I am using Node.js version 20.10.0 and npm version 10.2.5.

Comment: Please improve the visualization of your error code part.

Comment: Which command did you run? Can you also include the error log at `C:\\Users\\SteepRise\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\\_logs\\2023-12-19T06_58_29_179Z-debug-0.log`?

Comment: @creme332 i have used   npx create-react-app astro this command to new React App